# Update all branch in one commit

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have 10 branch and each branch contain same app with different name and logo and now i need to make a small change in master brach and need to reflect that change in all other branch is there possible to do?

Comment: It sounds like you made a poor choice in the way you defined your branches :(  Nevertheless, this link *might* help: https://superuser.com/a/627529

Answer (score 3):

Make the commit on master and merge master into all the branches. Write a small script to automate merging into each branch if you like.

> I have 10 branch and each branch contain same app with different name and logo...

This is the root of the problem. Git is not a configuration manager, nor a deployment system.

Long lived branches are always a headache. You have 10, and you're likely to have more. Instead, have one branch for the software. Put all things which can be configured into a configuration file written in something like JSON or YAML. When deployed the software will read a second user-written configuration file to override the defaults so the user can change the name and logo and other things.

If you're responsible for managing the configuration for multiple installations, you may consider putting each of those in their own repository if they're complex enough to need it. But only the configuration files, not the software.